# Getting error as java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/datastax/driver/core/policies/SpeculativeExecutionPolicy

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am using Java Driver Core 4.15.0 for cassandra but after running the code i am getting error as java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/driver/core/policies/SpeculativeExecutionPolicy

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/driver/core/policies/SpeculativeExecutionPolicy
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:537) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:537) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:570) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:697) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:640) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1484) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$BeanPostProcessorsRegistrar.registerSyntheticBeanIfMissing(EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.java:148) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$BeanPostProcessorsRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.java:137) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:354) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:143) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at com.yantriks.hazelcast.Application.main(Application.java:47) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.driver.core.policies.SpeculativeExecutionPolicy
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

I have changed the 3.x drivers to 4.x drivers and excluded the 3,x drivers that comes with spring boot and my code is built successfully but will running the application getting error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/driver/core/policies/SpeculativeExecutionPolicy

Answer (score 1):

DataStax Java driver 4.x is quite different from 3.x, so you can't simply bump dependency, you need to migrate your application to the new architecture.  Follow the [upgrade guide instructions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.14/upgrade_guide/#4-0-0) on how you can port your application.

Comment: I have migrated the application to 4.x but still getting the error

Comment: This class exist in the new driver but it has completely different package. Check you Spring Boot configuration, maybe old package name is referenced somewhere

Answer (score 0):

With 4.x, the class sits at [`com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.specex` package](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/4.x/core/src/main/java/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/core/specex/SpeculativeExecutionPolicy.java) whereas with 3.x, the same class sits at [`com.datastax.driver.core.policies` package](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.x/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/SpeculativeExecutionPolicy.java).